# Cannot find module 'mdb-calendar'

Tags: angular, material-design

I have recently started working with Material Design Bootstrap with Angular 7. I am trying to use their calendar plugin. I copied their `HTML` and `TS`. When I run the app I get an error of:

> Cannot find module 'mdb-calendar'.

I have tried to `npm install mdb calendar`, but it errors out. Any Ideas on how to fix this issue.

Comment: Have you added MdbCalenar to the imports array of your main module?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is mentioned on their site the **Full Page Calendar** is not included in  their MDB free bundle. So in order to use the plugin you have to buy it first. You can't use it unless you pay for it.

You can find more info [here](https://mdbootstrap.com/products/angular-full-calendar/)

Comment: Yup, you are right. It is only available through purchase.